# SQL SELECT the closest rows in ABS value & one on each side without using UNION ALL

Tags: sql

The items may not exist. For example, let's say a table

```
Table {
  String Id
  Timestamp Time
}
```

The existing records are:

```
Id     Time
a      2020-01-01 01:00
b      2020-01-01 02:00
c      2020-01-01 04:00
```

- The closest records of timestamp `2020-01-01 02:10` are `b` and `c`.
- The closest records of timestamp `2020-01-01 05:00` is only `c`.
- The closest records of timestamp `2020-01-01 00:00` is only `a`.

Is there a solution without using `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Is 23:45 closer to 00:00 than 01:00?

Comment: Only standard SQL language and functions can be used. Imagine the timestamp is just something can be cast to int64 (consider it as same as type int64 if that's easier). The timestamp contains a date as well (2020-01-01 01:00). For simplicity, I omitted it.